# Check how many times a substring appears in a string

Tags: vb.net

I need to create a MessageBox that is adapted to the number of times a word appears in a string. So I should be able to count how many times a word appears in a string. If this is more than 1 time, a certain message will appear. If this word occurs only 1 time, another message will appear. For the sake of clarity, I don't need to know how many times the substring occurs in the string. Only if it occurs more than once.

For example, I have the string `hello hi hello`. I am going to check the word 'hello'. The word comes in several times so a MessageBox saying the word appeared multiple times will show. I don't know how to do it, but I think it will be something in the neighborhood of the code I wrote below?

```
Dim stringToCheck, stringToFind As String
stringToCheck = "hello hi hello"
stringToFind = "hello"

If ... Then
   'The stringToFind appeared more than once in stringToCheck
   MessageBox.Show($"The string {stringToFind} was found more then once.", "Found multiple times")
Else
   'The stringToFind appeared only one time in stringToCheck
   MessageBox.Show($"The string {stringToFind} was found one time.", "Found once")
End If
```

I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If `IndexOf` and `LastIndexOf` return the same value then there's only one instance.

Comment: [Regex.Matches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches). E.g., `Dim count = Regex.Matches(stringToCheck, stringToFind).Count`

Comment: If you decided to use Regex, you need to be careful with `stringToFind` in case it contains special characters that are used by Regular Expressions. To be on the safe side, make sure to use `Regex.Escape(stringToFind)`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, unless they both return -1, in which case there is no instance.

Comment: @Idle_Mind, correct. I used the method from jmcilhinney and it works fine for me. In the situation where I'm using this for, there is at least one of `stringToFind` in `stringToCheck`, always. But thanks for commenting because I didn't know that! My question is solved.

Comment: While regex is valid, in my view it's a bit of a sledge hammer to bang in a nail.  Whats wrong with just using inStr()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are THREE possible outcomes that can occur:

1. No occurrences
2. One occurrence
3. Multiple occurrences

As suggested by jmcilhinney, you can use [IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_) and [LastIndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_LastIndexOf_System_String_) to help you make that determination.

If the string is not found, then -1 will be returned.  If the string is present (-1 not returned), but only occurs once, then the two values will be the same.  If the two values are not -1, and are different, then multiple occurrences are present.

Here's a simple `If...Else` block that shows all three states being checked for:

```
Dim stringToCheck, stringToFind As String
stringToCheck = "hello hi hello"
stringToFind = "hello"

Dim index1, index2 As Integer
index1 = stringToCheck.IndexOf(stringToFind)
If index1 <> -1 Then
    index2 = stringToCheck.LastIndexOf(stringToFind)
End If

If index1 = -1 Then
    MessageBox.Show($"The string {stringToFind} was NOT found.", "No occurrences")
ElseIf index1 = index2 Then
    MessageBox.Show($"The string {stringToFind} was found ONCE.", "One occurrence")
Else
    MessageBox.Show($"The string {stringToFind} was found MULTIPLE TIMES.", "Multiple occurrences")
End If
```

Comment: A slight improvement would be to check for `LastIndexOf()` _only if_ `IndexOf()` returns `>=0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Count = CInt((stringToCheck.Length - stringToCheck.Replace(stringToFind, "").Length) / stringToFind.Length)
```